# Find out last used text object

Tags: vimscript, repeated-commands, operator

I'm trying to figure out a way to make a repeatable operator insert. To do so I'm trying to make use of tpope/repeat. My idea is to set a repeatable call that repeats the last operation, repeating the last operation as it is doesn't work as insert is executed in place.

```
let g:last_insert_operator_textobj = ''
function s:repeat_insert()
    " TODO: detect that last action was the insert operator.
    " gi := (go insert) operator (which is working)
    call feedkeys("gi".g:last_insert_operator_textobj)
endfunction
command! repeat_insert call s:repeat_insert()
nmap (operator-insert-i-repeat) <plug>repeat_insert

function s:check_if_repeat_insert()
    " TODO: detect that this insert is associated to the
    " (operator-insert) and not a normal insert

    let g:last_insert_operator_textobj = somehow_get_last_used_textobject_keys()

    autocmd! InsertLeave * "call repeat#set("\<Plug>(operator-insert-i-repeat)", -1)
endfunction

command! check_if_repeat_insert call s:check_if_repeat_insert()
autocmd! InsertLeave * call check_if_repeat_insert
```

If I could figure out how to retrieve the keys of the last used text object `let g:last_insert_operator_textobj = somehow_get_last_used_textobject_keys()` then the rest of the script I think it would work. Figuring out the `" TODO: detect that this insert is associated to the (operator-insert) and not a normal insert` shouldn't be too complicated.

Comment: I don't think this is possible

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt but how does vim know what text object was used when you use the `.` command? It must know somehow, right?

Comment: Because Vim does keep track of the changes internally in the C source. That is nothing you can get access from VimScript.

Comment: What if instead you took the original from the other answer and added a onetime InsertLeave autocmd to do the repeat set before triggering the insert?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I see, makes sense, thank you for the guidance

Comment: @D.BenKnoble  I'm not sure if I did it correctly, but I tried to do that and the problem is that it repeats the insert at the current position and not at the text-object

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Maybe you are right, unfortunately I'm not very versed in vimscript, I'll give it another try

Comment: @D.BenKnoble The problem is that the operator triggers `startinsert` so if we repeat with tpope/repeat it will trigger the `startinsert` again, right? I need a way to record what was inserted and to which text object so I can repeat it I think

Comment: You can have last inserted text from the dot-register (`@.`). But note that it's _inserted_ text, not _put_ text or such.

Comment: @Matt That gives me an idea, thank you very much